# Alterar registros de outro usuário com credencial powershell

Tags: powershell

Alguém sabe como alterar um registro tendo a credencial criada.
Preciso alterar um valor dentro do HKEY_CURRENT_USER mas de outro usuário, vi que o cmdlets Set-Item tem o parametro -Credential, mas não consigo usa-lo, ele exibe o seguinte erro:
Set-Item : Não é possível recuperar parâmetros dinâmicos para o cmdlet. O provedor não dá suporte ao uso de credenciais. Execute a operação novamente sem especificar credenciais.

Answer (score 0):

1. Você não colocou a linha de código do comando `Set-Item`.
2. O parâmetro `Credential` é usado para executar um comando como se estivesse em outra conta. Você somente poderia acessar a ramificação `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` se soubesse a senha desta conta. Acredito que esta não seja a sua realidade.
3. No contexto de sua dúvida, é equivocado falar em *credencial criada*. Provavelmente o que você quis dizer é **perfil criado**.
4. Partindo da premissa que se quer alterar alguma informação na ramificação `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` de um **perfil criado**, estando em uma conta alheia, isto somente seria possível se a conta que executar o comando tiver poderes administrativos no sistema operacional.
5. Os passos para alterar o registro de um perfil criado que não esteja carregado não são triviais. Por exemplo, não há *comando nativo* em powershell para carregar e descarregar uma ramificação de registro. O comando externo "reg.exe" precisa ser utilizado.

```
##  Inicializa variáveis gerais
$EditorDeRegistro = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('System') + '\reg.exe'
$ArquivoDeRamificaçãoDoPerfil = 'D:\Usuários\João Ninguém\ntuser.dat'
$AcessoAoPerfil = 'Acesso'
Push-Location -LiteralPath ( Get-Location )

##  Libera memória
[GC]::Collect()
[GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

##  Carrega perfil
$ParâmetroSimplificado = @{
    FilePath = $EditorDeRegistro
    ArgumentList = 'LOAD', "HKU\$AcessoAoPerfil", """$ArquivoDeRamificaçãoDoPerfil"""
    Wait = $true
    WindowStyle = 'Hidden'
    PassThru = $true
}
$CódigoDeSaída = Start-Process @ParâmetroSimplificado
$CódigoDeSaída

##  Vai para a ramificação do perfil carregado
Set-Location -LiteralPath "Registry::HKEY_USERS\$AcessoAoPerfil"

##  Execute os comandos que quiser, desde que LiteralPath ou Path comece com '.\'
Set-ItemProperty -LiteralPath '.\Environment\' -Name 'teste de variável de ambiente' -Value 'teste de associação para variável de ambiente'

##  Descarrega perfil
$ParâmetroSimplificado.ArgumentList = 'UNLOAD', "HKU\$AcessoAoPerfil"
$CódigoDeSaída = Start-Process @ParâmetroSimplificado
$CódigoDeSaída

##  Libera memória
[GC]::Collect()
[GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

##  Retorna à pasta inicial
Pop-Location
```

6. Utilizo esta solução no powershell 2.0 (Windows 7) e no powershell 5.1 (Windows 10).